# Draw one solid inside another

Tags: pst-solides3d

I want to generate a couple of solids, one inside the other. I know I can do it in `pst-solides3d` because it of the first picture in the documentation. My intention is to create an ellipsoid inside another ellipsoid, quite simple really

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-4)(5,6)
\psset[pst-solides3d]{viewpoint=20 20 -10 rtp2xyz,Decran=15,lightsrc=viewpoint}
\defFunction{esfera2}(u,v)
{u cos v sin mul 5 mul}
{u sin v sin mul 4 mul}
{v cos           3 mul}
\defFunction{esfera1}(u,v)
{u cos v sin mul 3 mul}
{u sin v sin mul 2 mul}
{v cos           1 mul}
\psSolid[
    object=surfaceparametree,
    base=0 180 0 180,
    incolor=red,
    function=esfera1,
    linewidth=0.5\pslinewidth,
    ngrid=40
]%
\psSolid[
    object=surfaceparametree,
    base=0 180 0 180,
    incolor=white,
    opacity=0.5,
    function=esfera2,
    linewidth=0.5\pslinewidth,
    ngrid=40
]%
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

My code produces the following result

[image: incorrectly nested ellipsoids]

But my target is to make it look like the following picture (if you haven't seen it yet)

[image: Solides3d Manual cover picture]

I suppose part of the problem may be that my solids are parametrized surfaces. Any ideas?

Comment: I believe you'll need the `fusion` option - see section 9.3 of the documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to build a fusion object (collects all polygon surfaces) and, of course, to rotate the object for a look into the inside:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[solidmemory](-5,-4)(5,6)
\psset{viewpoint=20 -20 10 rtp2xyz,Decran=15,lightsrc=viewpoint,
  linewidth=0.1pt,action=none}
\defFunction{esfera2}(u,v)
  {u cos v sin mul 5 mul}
  {u sin v sin mul 4 mul}
  {v cos           3 mul}
\defFunction{esfera1}(u,v)
  {u cos v sin mul 3 mul}
  {u sin v sin mul 2 mul}
  {v cos           1 mul}
\psSolid[
    object=surfaceparametree,
    base=0 180 0 180,
    incolor=red,
    function=esfera1,
    ngrid=20,name=esfera1
]%
\psSolid[
    object=surfaceparametree,
    base=0 180 0 180,
    incolor=white,
    function=esfera2,
    ngrid=40,name=esfera2
]%
\psSolid[object=fusion,base=esfera1 esfera2,action=draw**]
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, as always! I have a series of follow up questions (related to your answer), I'm not sure if I should ask them here or if I should make them as separate questions.

Comment: aks a new question.

Comment: For some reason I cannot recall my followup questions. I guess this is a _case closed_